# You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page - after changed database prefix from 'wp_' to 'uae_'

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I am getting the message "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" after login with Administrator, after I renamed the table prefix.

I have already changed the $table_prefix value from wp-config.php file

Can anyone help me, how can I login as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do extra steps:

Run the query

```
SELECT * FROM `uae_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE '%wp_%'
```

And replace prefix `wp_` with `uae_`.

Do the same with `{$wpdb->prefix}usermeta` table, running query:

```
SELECT * FROM `uae_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%wp_%'
```

For more information take a look at the following [post](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-wordpress-database-prefix-to-improve-security/).